# 2007 vs 2010 Core API differences

Tags: development, core-api

As the title says, im trying to find out how different the core api's are between sharepoint 2010 and 2007.

dont care about packaging etc

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed from SP 2007 to 2010.

Start off by looking at the following MSDN articles and go from there:

- [New stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539826.aspx) in SPF 2010
- [New stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557323.aspx) in SPS 2010

Comment: ye but my concern is about the old stuff. so for eg how i access lists and the structure of sharepoint like sites fields... its also importent to note that i am working backwards. going from 2010 to 2007